# Android Socket not listen the port

Tags: android, kotlin

When i restarted the server app, client does not sending message. How can i fix?

Server:

```
var callable = Callable {
        try {
            serverSocket = ServerSocket(9100)
            socket = serverSocket!!.accept()
            while (true) {
                input = BufferedReader(
                    InputStreamReader(socket!!.getInputStream())
                )
            }
            Log.e("clientMessage", "${input.readLine()}")
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            try {
                socket?.close()
            } catch (ex: IOException) {
                ex.printStackTrace()
            }
        }
    }
```

Client :

```
 Runnable runnable = () -> {
            try {
                printerOutputStream = socketClient.getOutputStream();
                printerOutputStream.write(slipContentEscPos);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        };
        extPrinterExecutor.submit(runnable);
```

I'm not sure, should i make socket null?

Comment: You should restart the client too.

Comment: I know but i don't want this, because client is POS

Comment: Like that; 
https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/618iyqB7WiL._AC_SX466_.jpg